# Chocolatey command to verify installed package regardless of chocolatey 1/2 version

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

Chocolatey reworked "choco list" command. Since version 2.0 it no more accepts --lo (=local) argument and every call is considered against local packages.

`choco list --lo -e procmon`

- Chocolatey 1.1: it lists local package ("1 packages installed.")
- Chocolatey 2.0: error ("Invalid argument --lo. This argument has been removed from the list command and cannot be used.")

`choco list -e procmon`

- Chocolatey 1.1: it lists remote package ("1 packages found.")
- Chocolatey 2.0: it lists local package ("1 packages installed.")

I use PowerShell scripts to maintain 1000 machines with various chocolatey versions. I need universal command to find if chocolatey package is installed. The command which works regardless on chocolatey version. How to do it?

Comment: There is an [upgrade guide](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/guides/upgrading-to-chocolatey-v2-v6) and a [specific section dealing with this command](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/guides/upgrading-to-chocolatey-v2-v6#the-list-command-now-lists-local-packages-only-and-the-local-only-and-lo-options-have-been-removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both Chocolatey 1.* and 2.*, this should work:

```
choco list --lo --limit-output -e procmon
```

The `--limit-output` (or `-r`) in this case is restricting the output to a machine-readable delimited format (which I'd suggest using when parsing in PowerShell anyway, rather than matching on "x package found"). You could do something similar to the following:

```
$Result = choco list --lo -r -e vscode | ConvertFrom-Csv -delimiter "|" -Header Id,Version
```

Or, to just check that a package is installed:

```
if (choco list --lo -r -e procmon) {
  Write-Host "'procmon' is installed"
}
```

Comment: It works. Is there any explanation why Chocolatey 2.0 doesn't complain about "Invalid argument --lo" if it's used together with -r switch?

Comment: To quote the link provided by @pauby, "To ensure we do not break any existing automation, integrations or scripts using the --limit-output or -r along with -l, -a or one of their aliases, will continue to run and will not produce an error. Only a warning will be added to the logs. In a future release this will produce an error, so please ensure you remove -l, -a, and aliases, from any automations or scripts that you have."
There was a lot of internal debate around this. Please ensure you've removed --lo before 3.0!